# How do you reuse sets of jars in an Eclipse webapp?

Tags: java, eclipse

You can package up sets of jars e.g. all Hibernate dependencies into a User Library. In Eclipse if you go to Project - Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries, you can add your User Library. But in a webapp you need your jars to get copied to WEB-INF/lib. Is there any way to get Eclipse to do this automatically?

Comment: You're right, it's heavily cached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with the User Library.

1. Add the user library to project's build path.
2. Go to Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries
3. Select your user lib from the list.

At this point, Eclipse will know that the contents of user lib should be packaged into your web app's WEB-INF/lib directory. Note that this will happen at deployment or export. You will not actually see these jars in your project's source WEB-INF/lib directory.

These instructions are based on Eclipse "3.6" Helios. The steps are slightly different for older releases.

Comment: Konstantin you are a legend. The Eclipse UI is not very intuitive I must say, but I'm glad this can be done.

Comment: sweet just what I needed. Now I won't have multiple versions of jars files floating around